# how to refresh current popup in ajax when click

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to load the data from db using ajax and print it into model popup
but I need to refresh the current popup,if i click send.

i tried by reloading the model `chat_member.reload();`
but it doesn't works,

```
function chat_member(id) {
$('#chatform')[0].reset();
$('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
$('.help-block').empty();
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('member/ajax_view')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $('[name="UserId"]').val(data.UserId);
        $('#mchat').modal('show');
        $('.modal-title').text(data.UserName);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('member/ajax_chats')?>/" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) { // var msg2 = data.join('<br />');
         var mchat = "
        <
        table class = 'table table-striped table-bordered' >
            <
            tr >
            " +  " <
            td > < /td> < /
        tr > <
            /thead> <
        tbody > ";
        right ">11:00</span></div>';
        var msg1 = data.join('<br />');
        $('#messages').html(msg1);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
}
```

Comment: First, check the code, there's error on it

Comment: its working code

Comment: just use chat_member() instead chat_member.reload()

Comment: **that popup coming with empty result,**    success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.status)
            {
                reload_table();
                $("#chatform")[0].reset();
                chat_member();
            }

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, complete with all scripts and check the error on mchat variable.

Comment: okay thanks.............